# gvfs-afc-volume-monitor uses a lot of CPU

Tags: performance, 9.10, cpu-load, gvfs

In my Ubuntu 9.10 installation, I notice that the process gvfs-afc-volume-monitor causes my CPU core to go to 100% (that means for my dual-core machine to 50%).

Killing this process helps, but I see it repeating later on (not sure if this happens after restart/relogin or not).

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are suffering from this bug or something similar

[/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor kills polar bears](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usbmuxd/+bug/656009)

Not sure about the title of the bug but the more your processor is being used the more electricity it needs etc....

I'm not sure whether you can remove the package but you might "limit" the process with 
[cpulimit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/) until the update of libusbmuxd comes out for 9.10 if it does!

Comment: Thanks, I do connect my iPhone once in a while, which probably triggers this process, but I didn't see the connection with this program called 'gvfs-afc-volume-monitor'. So the best fix is to upgrade to a new(er) version that contains the patch, but alternatives are either damage control (cpulimit) or removing this daemon altogether. I just cannot see the impact of doing the latter, what functionality may I miss in the future?

Comment: Found this http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gvfs-list/2009-July/msg00002.html

Comment: It gives more info about what the package does and it sounds like removing it might be a bad idea plus you want get an update if any. However putting the brakes on with cpulimit is non destructive and you can "take the brake off" before plugging in your phone by attaching a kill cpulimit to a launcher and a restart to another and either leave them on the desktop (ugly) or make a custom menu "iphone" and drop them in there. Sounds like a hack but alot of linux is a combination of hacks which can cause problems later on sometimes but if it works it works.